# How to create a kql query between dates

Tags: kql

I am new to KQL and I am struggling to create a report that shows closed tickets between specific dates.
I've tried this query but no results:

```
SELECT COUNT('Tickets.Ticket ID') as closed, 'Tickets.Ticket ID', 'Tickets.Full Name', 
'Tickets.Subject', 'Tickets.Priority', 'Tickets.Creation Date', 'Tickets.Resolved Date' FROM 'Tickets' 
WHERE 'Tickets.Is Resolved' = '1' AND 'Tickets.Status' = 'Closed' AND 'Tickets.Resolved Date' = '2020- 
05-01' and 'Tickets.Department' =  'cloud Services' multigroup BY 'Tickets.Resolved Date':Day, 
'Tickets.Owner'
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using Azure Data Explorer to run this query, if so it seems that you are looking for something like this:

```
Tickets
| where IsResolved == 1 and Status=="Closed" and startofday(ResolvedDate) == datetime(2020-05-01) and Department == "cloud Services multi"
| summarize closed = count() by Owner
```

But the SQL is unclear since some columns in the select clause are not specified in the group by.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I used and it works:

```
SELECT COUNT('Tickets.Ticket ID') as closed, 'Tickets.Ticket ID', 'Tickets.Full Name', 
'Tickets.Subject', 'Tickets.Priority', 'Tickets.Creation Date', 'Tickets.Resolved Date' 
FROM 'Tickets' WHERE  'Tickets.Status' = 'Closed' AND 'Tickets.Resolved Date' >='2020- 
05-25' and 'Tickets.Resolved Date' <='2020-05-26' AND 'Tickets.Department' =  ' 
TeamName' multigroup BY 'Tickets.Resolved Date':Day, 'Tickets.Owner'
```